# Not able to switch database after defining Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, multi-tenant

I'm working on a multitenant architecture and we've to deal with a dynamic creation and switching of databases.

The problem I'm facing is that I wrote the entire code of switching database at the AOP level and then at the controller or service level I'm not able to make another switch.

**AOP class**

```java
/**
 * The type Api util.
 */
@Aspect
@Component
@Order(2)
public class APIUtil {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(APIUtil.class);
    private final SchoolMasterService schoolMasterService;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Api util.
     *
     * @param schoolMasterService the school master service
     * @param helperService
     */
    public APIUtil(SchoolMasterService schoolMasterService) {
        this.schoolMasterService = schoolMasterService;
    }

    /**
     * Around controller methods object.
     *
     * @param proceedingJoinPoint the proceeding join point
     * @return the object
     * @throws Throwable the throwable
     */
    @Around("execution(* com.example.board.controller.*.*(..))")
    public Object aroundControllerMethods(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        log.info("All schools loaded!");
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
        schoolMasterService.findAllMasters();
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        String tenantID = request.getHeader(XTENANTID).trim();
        return filterByHeader(tenantID, proceedingJoinPoint);
    }

   private Object filterByHeader(String tenantID, ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        SchoolMaster schoolMaster = schoolMasterService.findBySchoolId(Long.parseLong(tenantID));
        log.info(format("Current school is %s", schoolMaster.getDataSourceKey()));
        TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(schoolMaster.getDataSourceKey());
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

**CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl class**

```java
@Component
public class CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl implements CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Override
    public String resolveCurrentTenantIdentifier() {
        String currentDataSourceKey = TenantContext.getCurrentTenant();
        if (Objects.isNull(currentDataSourceKey)) {
            currentDataSourceKey = DEFAULT_TENANT_ID;
        }
        logger.debug("currentDataSourceKey {}", currentDataSourceKey);
        return currentDataSourceKey;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validateExistingCurrentSessions() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl class**

```java
@Component(MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.BEAN_ID)
public class MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {
    /**
     * The constant BEAN_ID.
     */
    public static final String BEAN_ID = "multiTenantConnectionProvider";
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7395318315512114572L;

    @Autowired
    private TenantDataSource tenantDataSource;

    private Logger log;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Multi tenant connection provider.
     */
    public MultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl() {
        log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
        log.debug("selectAnyDataSource , returning dafault tenantid");
        return tenantDataSource.getDataSource(DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        log.debug("selected Datasource {} ", tenantIdentifier);
        return tenantDataSource.getDataSource(tenantIdentifier);
    }
}
```

**TenantDataSource class**

```java
@Component
public class TenantDataSource {
    private final Map<Object, Object> tenantDataSourcesMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantDataSource.class);

    private final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateObject;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new Tenant data source.
     *
     * @param properties the properties
     * @param source     the source
     * @param object     the object
     */
    public TenantDataSource(DataSourceProperties properties, DataSource source, JdbcTemplate object) {
        this.dataSourceProperties = properties;
        this.dataSource = source;
        this.jdbcTemplateObject = object;
    }

    /**
     * Add default datasource to map.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    void addDefaultDatasourceToMap() {
        tenantDataSourcesMap.put(DEFAULT_TENANT_ID, dataSource);
    }

    /**
     * Gets data source.
     *
     * @param dataSourceName the data source name
     * @return the data source
     */
    public DataSource getDataSource(String dataSourceName) {
        DataSource currentDatasource = null;
        log.debug("getDataSource().dataSourceName {}", dataSourceName);
        if (tenantDataSourcesMap.containsKey(dataSourceName)) {
            currentDatasource = (DataSource) tenantDataSourcesMap.get(dataSourceName);
        }
        return currentDatasource;
    }

    /**
     * Load tenant boolean.
     *
     * @param tenantDatasource the tenant datasource
     * @return the boolean
     */
    public boolean loadTenant(SchoolMaster tenantDatasource) {
        try {
            if (!verifyPort(tenantDatasource))
                return false;
            DataSource temp = createDataSource(tenantDatasource);
            boolean result = verifyConnection(temp);
            if (result) {
                tenantDataSourcesMap.putIfAbsent(tenantDatasource.getDataSourceKey(), temp);
            }
            return result;
        } catch (Exception h) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Load all tenants.
     *
     * @param tenantDatasourcesList the tenant datasources list
     */
    public void loadAllTenants(List<SchoolMaster> tenantDatasourcesList) {
        tenantDatasourcesList.forEach(tenant -> tenantDataSourcesMap.putIfAbsent(tenant.getDataSourceKey(), createDataSource(tenant)));
    }

    /**
     * Create data source data source.
     *
     * @param tenantDatasource the tenant datasource
     * @return the data source
     */
    public DataSource createDataSource(SchoolMaster tenantDatasource) {
        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = null;
        if (Objects.nonNull(tenantDatasource)) {
            String url = JDBCMYSQL + tenantDatasource.getSchoolIP().trim() + ":" + tenantDatasource.getDataSourcePort().trim() + SLASH + tenantDatasource.getDataSourceKey().trim() + "?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=true";
            hikariDataSource = (HikariDataSource) DataSourceBuilder.create()
                    .driverClassName(dataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName())
                    .username(tenantDatasource.getDataSourceUserName()).password(tenantDatasource.getDataSourcePassword())
                    .url(url)
                    .build();
            setConnectionPooling(hikariDataSource);
        }
        return hikariDataSource;
    }

    /**
     * Create schema.
     *
     * @param dataSourceName the data source name
     * @throws SQLException the sql exception
     */
    public void createSchema(String dataSourceName) throws SQLException {
        if (tenantDataSourcesMap.containsKey(dataSourceName)) {
            jdbcTemplateObject.execute(CREATE_SCHEMA + " " + dataSourceName);
            jdbcTemplateObject.execute(USE_SCHEMA + " " + dataSourceName);
            DataSource currentDataSource = (DataSource) tenantDataSourcesMap.get(dataSourceName);
            ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("dbscripts/schema.sql");
            try (Connection connection = currentDataSource.getConnection()) {
                ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(connection, new EncodedResource(resource, "UTF-8"));
            }
            jdbcTemplateObject.execute(USE_SCHEMA + " " + DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Drop schema.
     *
     * @param dataSourceName the data source name
     */
    public void dropSchema(String dataSourceName) {
        if (tenantDataSourcesMap.containsKey(dataSourceName)) {
            DataSource currentDataSource = (DataSource) tenantDataSourcesMap.get(dataSourceName);
            JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(currentDataSource);
            template.execute(DROP_SCHEMA + " " + dataSourceName);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets connection pooling.
     *
     * @param hikariDataSource the hikari data source
     */
    private void setConnectionPooling(HikariDataSource hikariDataSource) {
        hikariDataSource.setMinimumIdle(2);
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(5);
        hikariDataSource.setIdleTimeout(100000);
        hikariDataSource.setMaxLifetime(3000000);
        hikariDataSource.setConnectionTimeout(200000);
        hikariDataSource.setLeakDetectionThreshold(2100);
        hikariDataSource.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
        hikariDataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
    }


    /**
     * Verify connection boolean.
     *
     * @param currentDatasource the current datasource
     * @return the boolean
     */
    private boolean verifyConnection(DataSource currentDatasource) {
        try (Connection ignored = currentDatasource.getConnection()) {
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Verify port boolean.
     *
     * @param tenantDataSource the tenant data source
     * @return the boolean
     */
    private boolean verifyPort(SchoolMaster tenantDataSource) {
        return tenantDataSource.getDataSourcePort().trim().chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit);
    }
}
```

**TenantContext class**

```java
public final class TenantContext {
    private static final ThreadLocal<String> currentTenant = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);

    private TenantContext() {
    }

    /**
     * Gets current tenant.
     *
     * @return the current tenant
     */
    public static String getCurrentTenant() {
        return currentTenant.get();
    }

    /**
     * Sets current tenant.
     *
     * @param tenant the tenant
     */
    public static void setCurrentTenant(String tenant) {
        currentTenant.set(tenant);
    }

    /**
     * Clear.
     */
    public static void clear() {
        currentTenant.remove();
    }
}
```

At the controller/service level, I'm not able to switch the database using `TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(String identifier)`
yet I'm able to do the same thing on AOP.

What is the reason for this? Any way how to fix this?

I would be really grateful for any help.

I've added the example of the Service Code

Where I need to switch database twice which is not being possible.

```java
 @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public List<SyllabusListingResponseDto> getSyllabusByBoardId(Long rackId, Long languageId) {
        logger.info("getSyllabusByBoardId Method called in BoardManagementServiceImpl");
        ResourceRackModel resourceRackModel = resourceRackService.getByRackIdAndStatus(rackId, ACTIVE_STATUS);
        if (Objects.nonNull(resourceRackModel)) {
            TenantContext.setCurrentTenant(DEFAULT_TENANT_ID);
            List<Long> rackIds = resourceRackService.findAllRackIdsByBoardId(rackId);
            rackIds.add(rackId);
            ResourceRackModel boardModel = resourceRackModel;
            if (!boardModel.getParentPath().isEmpty()) {
                String[] ids = resourceRackModel.getParentPath().split(",", 2);
                boardModel = resourceRackService.getByRackIdAndStatus(Long.parseLong(ids[INT_ZERO]), ACTIVE_STATUS);
            }
            TenantContext.setCurrentTenant("S_" + 1);
            BoardVersionModel activeVersionModel = boardVersionRepository.findByBoardIdAndStatusAndVersionStatus(boardModel.getRackId(), ACTIVE_STATUS, ACTIVE_STATUS);
            ContentCountDto contentCountDto = new ContentCountDto().setStatus(true).setRackIds(rackIds).setActiveBoardVersionId(activeVersionModel.getVersionId().toString());
            ResponseModel responseModel = nemrSTCManagementClient.findContentCount(Common.getTenantId(), contentCountDto).getBody();
            if (Objects.nonNull(responseModel)) {
                Map<String, List<String>> lookup = (Map<String, List<String>>) responseModel.getObject();
                String languageCode = languageMasterService.findByIdAndStatus(languageId, ACTIVE_STATUS).getLanguageCode();
                String defaultLanguageCode = languageMasterService.findByIdAndStatus(resourceRackModel.getDefaultLanguageId(), ACTIVE_STATUS).getLanguageCode();
                List<ResourceRackModel> resourceRackModels = resourceRackService.findByParentIdAndStatus(rackId, ACTIVE_STATUS);
                if (resourceRackModels.isEmpty()) {
                    return Collections.emptyList();
                }
                Map<Integer, String> rackTypes = new HashMap<>();
                return getResult(languageId, lookup, new SyllabusListingResponseDto(), boardModel, languageCode, defaultLanguageCode, resourceRackModels, rackTypes);
            }
        }
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
```

Comment: On a quick review I couldn't find the controller/service code where you are trying to set the `identifier`. Could you please update the question or point to that code ?

Comment: Hi, I've added.

Comment: By any chance the service falls in the package `com.example.board.controller.` ?  Have you debug the code to check if the `TenantContext.setCurrentTenant()` from the service code sets the tenant_id as expected ?

Comment: Yes, TenantContext.getCurrentTenant() returns me the correct identifier but it does not switch to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As I have not used `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` so not sure at what point the `datasource` is chosen by the framework.
2. But I have a great suspicion it is done by the `interceptor` auto created by  `@Transactional`, and the framework never reads the `TenantContext` inside the method. I.e one datasource for one transactional method.
   So may be worth identifying if my suspicion is true.

   - You can put a breakpoint at the following :

   ```
       logger.info("getSyllabusByBoardId Method called in BoardManagement...");
   ```

   - Then clear the console logs when the break point is there.
   - Then let the method execute and see if any of the following logs are printed when you step through your service method lines.

   ```
       log.debug("selectAnyDataSource , returning dafault tenantid");
   ```

   ```
      log.debug("selected Datasource {} ", tenantIdentifier);
   ```
3. If my suspicion in step 2 is correct, then either you have to remove the `@Transactional` annotation or split the methods in two and set the correct `TenantContext.setCurrentTenant` for each method in the controller before calling the service method.

Comment: Thank you, man! It was @Transactional. It spent two days figuring the reason but never knew Transactional creates Interceptor.