# Spring Boot SQL JPA not using correct replica

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa

I have an application where I am trying to distribute reads & writes between two replicas. For some reason JPA is only using my read-replica, not the write replica. The write replica is the primary replica. The result is that when I use JPA to try and write data I get and 'UPDATE command denied' error because it is using the read only datasource. I have tried doing my own annotation and using the @Transactional annotation. Both annotations are called via AOP with the correct datasource but JPA will not use it.

FYI Spring JDBC works correctly via the custom annotation. This is strictly a JPA issue. Below is some code:

**My AOP class:**

```
@Aspect
@Order(20)
@Component
public class RouteDataSourceInterceptor {

    @Around("@annotation(com.kenect.db.common.annotations.UseDataSource) && execution(* *(..))")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        try {
            MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
            Method method = signature.getMethod();
            UseDataSource annotation = method.getAnnotation(UseDataSource.class);
            RoutingDataSource.setDataSourceName(annotation.value());
            return pjp.proceed();
        } finally {
            RoutingDataSource.resetDataSource();
        }
    }

    @Around("@annotation(transactional)")
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Transactional transactional) throws Throwable {
        try {
            if (transactional.readOnly()) {
                RoutingDataSource.setDataSourceName(SQL_READ_REPLICA);
                Klogger.info("Routing database call to the read replica");
            } else {
                RoutingDataSource.setDataSourceName(SQL_MASTER_REPLICA);
                Klogger.info("Routing database call to the primary replica");
            }
            return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            RoutingDataSource.resetDataSource();
        }
    }
}
```

**My RoutingDataSource class:**

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> currentDataSourceName = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static synchronized void setDataSourceName(String name) {
        currentDataSourceName.set(name);
    }

    public static synchronized void resetDataSource() {
        currentDataSourceName.remove();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return currentDataSourceName.get();
    }
}
```

**AbstractDynamicDataSourceConfig**

```
public abstract class AbstractDynamicDataSourceConfig {

    private final ConfigurableEnvironment environment;

    public AbstractDynamicDataSourceConfig(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    protected DataSource getRoutingDataSource() {
        Map<String, String> props = DBConfigurationUtils.getAllPropertiesStartingWith("spring.datasource", environment);
        List<String> dataSourceNames = DBConfigurationUtils.getDataSourceNames(props.keySet());

        RoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();
        Map<Object, Object> dataSources = new HashMap<>();
        DataSource masterDataSource = null;

        for (String name : dataSourceNames) {
            DataSource dataSource = getDataSource("spring.datasource." + name);
            dataSources.put(name, dataSource);

            if (masterDataSource == null && name.toLowerCase().contains("master")) {
                masterDataSource = dataSource;
            }
        }

        if (dataSources.isEmpty()) {
            throw new KenectInvalidParameterException("No datasources found.");
        }

        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSources);

        if (masterDataSource == null) {
            masterDataSource = (DataSource) dataSources.get(dataSourceNames.get(0));
        }

        routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(masterDataSource);

        return routingDataSource;
    }

    protected DataSource getDataSource(String prefix) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(environment.getProperty(prefix + ".jdbcUrl"));
        hikariConfig.setUsername(environment.getProperty(prefix + ".username"));
        hikariConfig.setPassword(environment.getProperty(prefix + ".password"));

        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }
}
```

**application.yaml**

```
spring:
  datasource:
    master:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://my-main-replica
      username: some-user
      password: some-password
    read-replica:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://my-read-replica
      username: another-user
      password: another-password
```

If I use the annotation on with JDBC template then it works as expected:

THIS WORKS:

```
// Uses main replica as it is not specified
public Message insertMessage(Message message) {

    String sql = "INSERT INTO message(" +
            " `conversationId`," +
            " `body`)" +
            " VALUE (" +
            " :conversationId," +
            " :body" +
            ")";
    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("conversationId", message.getConversationId());
    parameters.addValue("body", message.getBody());
       
    namedJdbcTemplate.update(sql, parameters);
}

// Uses read replica
@UseDataSource(SQL_READ_REPLICA)
public List<Message> getMessage(long id) {

    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("id", id);
    String sql = "SELECT " +
            " conversationId," +
            " body" +
            " FROM message"
            " WHERE id = :id";

    return namedJdbcTemplate.query(sql, parameters, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Message.class));
}
```

If I use a JPA interface it always uses the read replica:

THIS FAILS:

```
@Repository
public interface MessageJpaRepository extends JpaRepository<MessageEntity, Long> {

    // Should use the main-replica but always uses the read-replica
    @Modifying
    @Query(value =
            "UPDATE clarioMessage SET" +
                    " body = :body" +
                    " WHERE id = :id" +
                    " AND organizationId = :organizationId",
            nativeQuery = true)
    @Transactional
    int updateMessageBodyByIdAndOrganizationId(@Param("body") String body, @Param("id")long id, @Param("organizationId")long organizationId);
}
```

So I am just getting the error below when I try to use the main-replica. I have tried using the `@UseDataSource` annotation and AOP does actually intercept it. But, it still uses the read-replica.

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: UPDATE command denied to user 'read-replica-user'@'read replica IP' for table 'message'
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

- When you use `@UseDataSource`, it is working so it seems rules out any issues with implementation of aspect.
- And When you `@Transactional`, it uses the secondary replica, regardless of your your AOP being invoked. My suspicion is by the `TransactionInterceptor` created by spring is invoked before your `RouteDataSourceInterceptor`. You can try the following:
- Put a breakpoint in your aop method as well as a break point in `org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke` method to see which one invokes first. You want your interceptor invoked first
- If your interceptor is not invoked first, I would modify your interceptor to have high order as follows.

```
    @Aspect
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Component
    public class RouteDataSourceInterceptor {
```

- I still don't understand how you are telling `TransactionInterceptor` to choose the `DataSource` you set in `RouteDataSourceInterceptor`. I have not used multi tenant setup but recently I came across a question which I helped to solve and I can see it is implementing `AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl`. So I hope you have something similar. [Not able to switch database after defining Spring AOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62889154/not-able-to-switch-database-after-defining-spring-aop/62892862#62892862)